# Windows 7 Installer Freezes

Tags: windows-7, freeze, windows-installer

I just purchased a new pc and hdd. I can get into the bios and set the boot order of my devices.  When I run my Windows 7 installation disc, the computer reads windows files fine and gets to the language and region selection screen. On this screen, the installer seems to be frozen.

Answer (score 4):

After much Googling, I somehow stumbled across this post: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/42845-63-help-windows-freezing-install-screen. Who'd have thought that the usb ports on the back of the machine are recognized by the system in the bios but are not active during execution of the Windows installer? The solution was to plug my usb mouse and keyboard into the ports on the front of my machine.

Comment: Nice detective work!